# How to serve static files inside JAR?

Tags: jetty, classpath, static-files

Is there a lightweight alternative (while still using Jetty) to [WebAppContext](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html) for serving static files from a JAR file on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classes in the [com.sun.net.httpserver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html) package for serving static files

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that I still want to use Jetty.